# VBA strip string of double quotes when passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to update a row in a table in my database, which is of data type:  `date`.
I am using a stored procedure, and I am retrieving the value to update to from a TextBox as a string. My problem is that a string has double quotes (") and when I'm passing my value in the string, it keeps the double quotes and SQL-Server only supports single quotes ('').

```
        intIndividualSessionID = Me.IndividualSession_ListBox.Column(1)
        sessionDate = Me.DateTextBox.Value
        startTime = Me.StartTimeTextBox.Value
        endTime = Me.EndTimeTextBox.Value
    
        'Setup ADO objects to run stored procedure
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        cn.Open strCon
        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        With cmd
                .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
        
            'Create string to include parameters
            CommandText = "Exec UpdateIndividualSession " & intClientID & "," & intIndividualSessionID & "," & "sessionDate" & "," & "startTime" & "," & "endTime" & ";"
            .CommandTimeout = 0
            .Execute
        End With
```

this gives me an error when I run.

> Error converting datatype nvarchar to date."

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? If you use parameters you solve all these problems, and make your code safer.

Comment: mysql does not have exec statement, it uses call statement to execute a stored procedure and also mysql may understand nvarchar as an alias, but would never reference nvarchar in an error message. This means you are using ms sql server, not mysql. You should be using parameters, not string concatenation to pass parameters to an sql statement.

Comment: @Shadow oh my I meant SQL-Server, my mistake, but I see, this is not a live database, just something im working on for a school project, thought id take the easy route but its causing me more issues than helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Parameter` objects, not concatenating strings - you are passing the literal value `sessionDate`, not your local `sessionDate` variable's value.

SQL Server uses single quotes to delimit strings, so I'm not sure why you are using double quotes here, and you could double them up to escape them but not nudging you away from that direction would be unwise.

Make the `CommandType` be `adCmdStoredProc`, and the `CommandText` should be just the name of the stored procedure - then use the `Command` object to create and append the `Parameters`:

```
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.CommandText = "UpdateIndividualSession"
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(...)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(...)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(...)
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(...)
.Execute
```

That's the beauty of using `Command` and a stored procedure: now it's the server's job to deal with the parameter values, and no delimiter gets in the way.

Make sure `sessionDate` is declared with `Dim sessionDate As Date`, and consider using an explicit conversion function instead of a direct assignment, but the general idea is to send a `Date` value for an `adDate` server parameter.